# How to remove unused product attribute options in Magento 2

Tags: magento

How do I remove duplicate option values for product attributes in Magento 2?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Boiled down the question to what the user is actually wondering.